# JBOSS EAP deployed jersey servlet and JSON output issue

Tags: json, servlets, jersey, jboss-eap-6

I have deployed WAR file with jersey servlet on JBoss EAP 6.1+ server. I am able to /get request and process successfully. I want to return class object as JSON output. When I run application in the localhost get JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error.

Can anyone provide input to solve the issue?
my web.xml is...

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value><package>.ws.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

## JSONservice.java

```
@Path("/json/palm")
public class JSONService {

    static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JSONService.class);

    private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName(
            "urn:us:gov:uspto:patent:palm:service:bibdata:V1.0",
            "BibDataRetrievalService");

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public CaseVo getTrackInJSON() {

        CaseVo patentCase = new CaseVo();
        ...
        ...
        return CaseVo;
}

CaseVo.java
============

public class CaseVo {
 public String prop1;
 public String prop2;
   ...
   setter and getter and toString()
}
```

## pom.xml

javax.ws.rs</groupId> jsr311-api</artifactId> 
            1.1.1</version> </dependency> -->
        
            com.sun.jersey
            jersey-server
            1.17.1
        
        
            com.sun.jersey
            jersey-core
            1.17.1
        
        
            com.sun.jersey
            jersey-servlet
            1.17.1
        
        
            javax.enterprise
            cdi-api
            1.2

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-validation_1.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.bval.bundle</artifactId>
        <version>0.3-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.serp</groupId>
        <artifactId>serp</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Jersey and not just JAX-RS? I see you're setting some RESTEasy settings which is the JAX-RS implementation bundled with EAP. Also you have several dependencies that should removed or marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: James, As per your suggestion, I replaced Jersey with just JAX-RS and also added <scope>provided</scope>. Issue resolved! Thank You! Do we know of any known issues with JBoss EAP and Jersey compatibility?

Comment: Jersey is a JAX-RS implementation and in fact the reference implementation. RESTEasy is also a JAX-RS implementation. EAP uses RESTEasy for it's JAX-RS implementation.